# Simplifying Boolean Expression with steps

Tags: boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I am new to Boolean algebra and not what to do with negative expressions and if you can explain it in steps

```
A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be read as not A and not B and not C or not A and not B and C.....
The ' just means that input inverted, where if it is with out the ' not inverted.  The + are or gates while having the letters back to back or multiplying them would be an and gate.

So A'B'C'+ A'B'C + A'BC + AB'C + ABC could be seen as 0*0*0 + 0*0*1 + 0*1*1 + 1*0*1 + 1*1*1
where if the inputs on A, B and C correspond to one of the sets the you will get a 1 as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First let's make an agreement of the notation used in expression
**A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC+AB'C+ABC**:

```
      Notation                Bool operation      Priority  CPU instruction 
' behind Bool variable         negation            highest      NEG
two adjacent variables         logical AND          high         AND
+ between two variables        logical OR           low          OR 
( )                          priority of oper.     increased
```

Your expression can be then rewritten to

```
((NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (NOT C)) OR 
((NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (    C)) OR
((NOT A) AND (    B)     AND (C)) OR
((    A) AND (NOT B)     AND (C)) OR
((    A) AND (    B)     AND (C))
```

The next step is to calculate the contents of all innermost parenthesis,
for instance let's compute **(NOT A)** to another variable named **notA**.
This allows to get rid of one level of parenthesis:

```
(notaA AND notB AND notC) OR
(notA  AND notB AND    C) OR
(notA  AND    B AND    C) OR
(   A  AND notB AND    C) OR
(   A  AND    B AND    C)
```

Repeat the calculation until there are no more parenthesis left:

```
notAnotBnotC OR notAnotBC OR notABC OR AnotBC OR ABC
```